Unable to get soap response after Graphql mesh upgrade
I have upgraded graphql-mesh/soap versions and other dependencies.
And my soap wsdl is using soap1.1 features.
After update I am unable to connect to soap client as it is returning 500 error due to version mismatch in namespace created by graphqlmesh soap in request.
I have configured soap handler in .meshrc.yaml with source url
Expected namespace in request body -http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
And generating - http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope

Manage to modify the namespace using custome-fect.
sources:
  - name: myser
    handler:
      soap:
        source: http://127.0.0.1:8080/myser.wsdl
        operationHeaders:
          Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
          Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate   
customFetch: ./custom-fetch.ts     
serve:
  endpoint: /api/graphql 
  port: 5000

my custom -fetch.js
import { fetch } from '@whatwg-node/fetch'
 
export default async function ( url: string, options: RequestInit = {} )
{
    console.log(url)
    if ( url === 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/myserv' )
    {
        console.log(options.body)
        if (options.body && typeof options.body === 'string')
        {
            let body = options.body;
            if (typeof body === 'string') {
                body = body.replace(
                  '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">',
                  '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >'
                );
        

                options.body = body;
                console.log('Modified xml body:', options.body);
            }        
        }
    }
    
    return fetch(url, options);
}

